# What's the difference between the Kotlin and the Gradle version setting and IDE?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm wondering if the difference of the kotlin version between gradle setting and ide.
I can see the kotlin version of IDE(Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin).
And there is another Kotlin version defined in `build.gradle`.
I want to know the difference.
I think that the version in `buidl.gradle` affects to real project and some dependencies.
And the version in IDE affects when we write the code.

Is my guess right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDE kotlin version help live coding style i.e. you get kotlin suggestion in that version.
Gradle kotlin version is your project version i.e. it compile your code on that version.

These version may be different. Your IDE kotlin version may be updated than your gradle kotlin version.